# How to add new item to gridview in first position?

Tags: android, gridview

How do I add a new item to gridview in first postion.

```
protected void showList() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String userid = c.getString(Config.KEY_USERID);
            String thumburl = c.getString(Config.KEY_THUMBURL);

            HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<String, String>();
            persons.put(Config.KEY_USERID,  userid);
            persons.put(Config.KEY_THUMBURL, thumburl);

            personList.add(persons);

        }

        GridView listview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(NewRetriveData.this, personList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

After that I am adding new item to ArrayList Dynamically

```
HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<String, String>();
            persons.put(Config.KEY_USERID,  "sweety");
            persons.put(Config.KEY_THUMBURL, "www.sweety.com/hello.jpg");
```

After that i am reloading the Arraylist

```
GridView listview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(NewRetriveData.this, personList);
        listview.setAdapter(null);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want dynamically added array item show in GridView 1st Position.

Comment: i want to add new item in first position not reversing the grid item.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651946/how-to-set-the-first-item-in-gridview-with-default-value-and-populate-the-rest-o refer here

Comment: @praveen: You could use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager, here you can add a item at any position easily..
Recyclerview will provide insertAt(position) etc...

Answer (score 0):

First you globaly declare your hashmap.
Then add First raw data before start for loop.
That's do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create `addItem()` in your adapter

```
    public class CoustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context myContext;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

        public CoustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
            myContext = context;
            this.data = data;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        void addItem(HashMap<String, String> persons) {
            data.add(0, persons); // 0 for add it in starting index
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
  ...

}
```

then use it from your activity

```
HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<String, String>();
        persons.put(Config.KEY_USERID,  userid);
        persons.put(Config.KEY_THUMBURL, thumburl);

        adapter.addItem(persons);
```